# Issue while installing Scala IDE in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I am trying to install the Scala in Eclipse Galileo 3.5, but I got the following error:

Error Message:

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or 
more required items could not be found. Software being installed:
JDT    Weaving for Scala 2.0.0.beta08-29-201107121555-7d78460   
(org.scala-ide.sdt.weaving.feature.feature.group
   2.0.0.beta08-29-201107121555-7d78460) Missing requirement: JDT Weaving 2.1.3.e36x-20110622-1300   
(org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt 2.1.3.e36x-20110622-1300)   
requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.5.100' but it could not
be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: JDT Weaving for Scala
   2.0.0.beta08-29-201107121555-7d78460 (org.scala-ide.sdt.weaving.feature.feature.group
```

---

Answer (score 7):

[Scala IDE 2.0](http://www.scala-ide.org/) only works with Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7. If you want to use Eclipse 3.5 you have to go with an older version, 1.0.

From the web page:

> Current build is Scala IDE 2.0.0-beta8 with Scala 2.9.0.1 for Eclipse 3.6 and 3.7 (Helios and Indigo).
>
> For Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) and Scala 2.8.1.final support use the Scala IDE 1.0.0-milestones update site.

Comment: Which version of eclipse  is suitable for scala and groovy?

Comment: @niva: I recommend 3.6 or 3.7 for Scala. I don't know about Groovy.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it installing through market place.

[image]

Which works very fine without any problems.

you refer this link:https://youtu.be/DEvzfdlpruc

Comment: After I installed it, eclipse has a lot of errors and not working at all with error
`Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.`

Comment: which version eclipse you are using

Comment: I am using eclipse luna

Answer (score 2):

Get pre-installed/configured ScalaIDE for Eclipse provided by TypeSafe.
Ready and working out-of-box

http://typesafe.com/stack/scala_ide_download